# Can't import AAR library with @IntDef annotations

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, aar, annotation-processor

I have the following code in my library:

```
@Documented
@IntDef({OpacityAnimationType.NONE,
        OpacityAnimationType.BLINKING,
        OpacityAnimationType.SHINY,
        OpacityAnimationType.AURA,
})
public @interface OpacityAnimationType {
    int NONE = 0;
    int BLINKING = 1;
    int SHINY = 2;
    int AURA = 3;
}
```

In gradle for library I have

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["library" : "true"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
configurations {
    javadocDeps
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"

    javadocDeps "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

Which I deploy to JFrog BinTray, and then try to use it in my app. I have to exclude appcompat-v7 and support-annotations from library dependency, but I build still fails with:

> Error:Failed to resolve: annotationProcessor

Now I'm stuck, tried many things but nothing helps. I can't build main project with this library.
Do I need to implement any custom AnnotationProcessor to be able to use @IntDef's?

Comment: Also tried to remove from library, but it doesn't help
    javadocDeps "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"

Tried to remove @aar from library dependency in main project, but it didn't help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I've been able to overcome this issue!

It looks like in case of custom annotations custom annotation processor is also required. For now I've decided to skip creating custom annotation processor and not use custom annotations for enumerations with @IntDef.

But anyways, if your library uses existing annotations and you publish it on mavenCentral or jCenter or other repository and use it in other projects, that you'll need to add some magic to javadoc task.

It starts here:
https://github.com/vulko/AnimatedArcProgressView/blob/master/library/build.gradle with

```
    configurations {
        javadocDeps
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        compile("com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion") {
            transitive false;
        }   
        javadocDeps "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    }
```

and then continues in publishing gradle script here: https://github.com/vulko/AnimatedArcProgressView/blob/master/gradle/publish-library.gradle with:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.source

    // this is the magic
    classpath += configurations.javadocDeps

    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
```

Anyways, all the code can be found here:
https://github.com/vulko/AnimatedArcProgressView/

Answer (score 0):

Been googling this issue and looks like if there are any annotations in library, library needs an annotations project which will contain those. Not sure about the processor though, hopefully it wouldn't be needed, otherwise I'll have to switch from custom annotations to @IntDef with some static final int's instead.

There's also some gradle magic that is required to do this, and so far no good tutorials, but a bunch of code on github with processors and annotations. I'd like to avoid using custom processor, cause I simply don't need it.

Any ways, I'll try to keep this thread updated when I finally manage to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now the story continues.
I had to create a **annotations** submodule in library project for annotations, and I had to move @IntDef's out of it, otherwise it wouldn't be able to import any of android annotations to submodule. So I've moved @IntDef's to library, and they use custom annotations from submodule now.

Even though I'm able to build and deploy it, the library artifact can't be imported, cause:

> Error:Could not find
>   com.kvolkov.animatedprogressviews:annotations:unspecified. Searched in
>   the following locations: Required by:
>       project : > com.kvolkov.animatedprogressviews:library:1.0-RC5

I assume this happens because I need to deploy **annotations** submodule as a separate artifact now, which I can't do, since I wasn't able to match code from some tutorial for .gradle of annotations module with the plugins for bintray to deploy it there from studio...

Well, this is still not the end.
If any1 is interested or willing to help, you might take a look at current code of library here:
https://github.com/vulko/AnimatedArcProgressView

I'd be glad to recieve some help or advice, cause all info regarding this uses apt instead of annotation processor.